# Zend 2 callables vs Factories - too many factories?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have not found any answer to this question on SO so far but I think it is quite a common issue when you have a big Module.php file with a lot of callables that instantiate your services. I would like to refactor such Module.php service manager configuration into factory classes however it seems I would have to create a lot of such factories, basically one factory for one service. It can be done but seems a lot of work. Is it worth doing? I would like to ask you what you do normally in such situations - stick to callables (no point in refactoring, little gains) or create dozens of factory classes if necessary?
Cheers.

Comment: Just read http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/?joel.3.219431.12